# Cant change jquery.Validate messages Language to ES

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Guys my problem is that i cant change the default language of jquery.validate to spanish, as it says everywhere in the internet, i have added the localization/messages_es.js file after the validate.min.js but my messages still being showed in english.

```
<script src="../js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/localization/messages_es.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: That popup message is **not** coming from the jQuery Validate plugin.  The image indicates that your browser is only using HTML5 validation.  You likely have a JavaScript error... show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML required error message and not validate js error message.  check whether there is any error in your console.

Answer (score 0):

This popup message is **NOT** coming from the jQuery Validate plugin:

[image]

This is HTML 5 validation as part of your browser and triggered by inline HTML 5 validation attributes such as...

```
<select required="required" ....
```

When working properly, the jQuery Validate plugin *disables* the browser's default HTML 5 validation and inserts plain text messages immediately after each input element.

Since the plugin is not working, you have likely done one or more of the following...

- failed to properly include jQuery or the plugin
- failed to properly initialize the plugin
- some other syntax or JavaScript error?

Since you neglected to show us any code, we would have no idea what you've done wrong.  Check your JavaScript error console for clues.

Otherwise, the ES localization is working fine:  [jsfiddle.net/zkpn4czx/](http://jsfiddle.net/zkpn4czx/)